# How do I activate GitHub Pull Requests and Issues on VSCODE?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, installation

I'm trying to install 'GitHub Pull Requests and Issues' on VSCODE which worked but I can't do anything, like login to my GitHub account.

[image: ISSUE]

I already have Git installed on my Computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be on the GitHub Pull Request page. Click on the create new pull request button. Then choose a target branch to which you want to pull, and from which you want to pull.

When you click “Create”, if the branch is not yet pushed to the GitHub remote repository, the extension will ask whether you want to publish the branch and provide a dropdown menu for you to choose from.

The Create Pull Request, automatically allows you to review details in the pull request, in the Review Mode. You can add comments, reviewers, labels, and finally merge the pull request when it is ready to go.